# Динамический доступ к элементам View внутри ViewPager2

Tags: android, android-fragment, recyclerview, android-viewpager

Есть ViewPager2, адаптер - FragmentStateAdapter. ViewPager2 манипулирует однотипными фрагментами, внутри каждого из которых RecyclerView. Внутри RecyclerView - button элементы, состояние которых мне нужно изменять в зависимости от другого процесса. Проблема в том, что их состояние удаётся изменять только у первого и последнего фрагмента, потому что они нужным образом пересоздаются. Те фрагменты, что между ними, один раз создаются и не уничтожаются, и доступа, по каким-то причинам, к их RecyclerView нет.

```
profileFunctionFragment.fragmentAdapter.apply{
                            allFunctionsFragment.enabledButton(false, activeFunction) //успешно
                            friendsFragment.enabledButton(false, activeFunction) //не удается
                            wallFragment.enabledButton(false, activeFunction) //не удается
                            groupFragment.enabledButton(false, activeFunction) //не удается
                            mediaFragment.enabledButton(false, activeFunction) //успешно
```

Код адаптера:

```
class ViewPager2Adapter(fragment: Fragment): FragmentStateAdapter(fragment)  {
lateinit var allFunctionsFragment: ObjectFragment
lateinit var friendsFragment: ObjectFragment
lateinit var wallFragment: ObjectFragment
lateinit var groupFragment: ObjectFragment
lateinit var mediaFragment: ObjectFragment


override fun getItemCount(): Int = 5


override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {

    allFunctionsFragment = ObjectFragment(R.layout.fragment_all_function, R.id.fragment_groups_function, StorageFunctions.listOfFunctionsProfile,
            "allFunctionsFragment")
    friendsFragment = ObjectFragment(R.layout.fragment_friends, R.id.function_list_friends, StorageFunctions.listOfFunctionsFriends,
            "friendsFragment")
    wallFragment = ObjectFragment(R.layout.fragment_wall, R.id.function_list_wall, StorageFunctions.listOfFunctionsWall,
            "wallFragment")
    groupFragment = ObjectFragment(R.layout.fragment_groups, R.id.function_list_groups, StorageFunctions.listOfFunctionsForGroups,
            "groupFragment")
    mediaFragment = ObjectFragment(R.layout.fragment_media, R.id.function_list_media, StorageFunctions.listOfFunctionsMedia,
            "mediaFragment")
    lateinit var fragment: ObjectFragment
    when(position) {
        0 -> {
            fragment = allFunctionsFragment
            activeFragment = "allFunctionsFragment"
        }
        1 -> {
            fragment = friendsFragment
            activeFragment = "friendsFragment"
        }
        2 -> {
            fragment = wallFragment
            activeFragment = "wallFragment"
        }
        3 -> {
            fragment = groupFragment
            activeFragment = "groupFragment"
        }
        4 -> {
            fragment = mediaFragment
            activeFragment = "mediaFragment"
        }

    }
    return fragment
}

}
```

Код типового фрагмента:

```
class ObjectFragment(resource: Int, recyclerViewId: Int, data: MutableSet<Function>, tag: String) : Fragment() { //шаблон для всех фрагментов, остальные фрагменты - экземпляры этого класса
var resourceId = resource
var recyclerViewId = recyclerViewId
var data = data
var mTag = tag
var created = false
lateinit var rootView: View
lateinit var buttonList: RecyclerView


override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(resourceId, container, false)


    initViews()


    if (MainActivity.status) enabledButton(false, MainActivity.activeFunction)
    else enabledButton(true)

    return rootView
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    Log.i("infoCreated", "Уничтожен $mTag!!")
}

fun initViews(){
    buttonList = rootView.findViewById(recyclerViewId)
    buttonList.isNestedScrollingEnabled = false;
    buttonList.adapter = FunctionAdapter(context, data)
    created = true
    Log.i("infoCreated", "Инициализирован $mTag!!")
}



fun enabledButton(enabled: Boolean, textPosition: String = "plug"){
    for(i in data){
        i.enabledChangeItem = enabled
        if (textPosition != i.name)
            i.enabled = enabled
        i.enabledChangeItem = enabled
    }
   if (created) buttonList.adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged() //срабатывает только у перв. и посл.
    else Log.i("infoCreated", "не создан $mTag")
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была решена созданием фрагментов в другом месте, что повлекло за собой переиспользование одних и тех же фрагментов и своевременный доступ к их View